# Should I use several streams o a single loop?

Tags: java, loops, java-stream, coding-efficiency

Imagine we are working with this class:

```
public Student{
  String name;
  Integer age;
  Integer height;
  Integer weight;
}
```

Now we've got a list of students and we are asked something like:

- filter those whose name is "Jonh" and get the average age
- filter those whose name is "Mary" and get the biggest hight
- filter those whose name is "Ben" and get the smallest weight

I think thar a clean and understandble solution is to use lambdas to filter by name and get what is asked for:

```
List<Student> students = ...
double jonhAge = students.stream().filter(s->s.getName().equals("Jonh").mapToInt(s->s.getAge()).average()
double maryHeight = students.stream().filter(s->s.getName().equals("Mary").mapToInt(s->s.getHeight()).max()
double benWeight = students.stream().filter(s->s.getName().equals("Ben").mapToInt(s->s.getWeight()).min()
```

I guess that at least it is iterating over the list 3 times, and using a single loop with conditions might be more efficent:

```
double jonhAge = 0;
double jonhCount = 0;
double maryHeight = 0;
double benWeight = 1000;
for(Student s : students){
  if(s.getName.equals("Jonh")){
    jonhAge += s.getAge();
    jonhCount++;
  }else if(s.getName.equals("Mary")){
    if(s.getHeight()>maryHeight)
      maryHeight = s.getHeight();
  }else if(s.getName.equals("Ben")){
    if(s.getWeight()<benWeight )
      benWeight = s.getWeight();
  }
}
jonhAge = jonhAge / jonhCount;
```

I think that the first way is cleaner but the second one is faster. Am I right? Which one shoud I use?
Imagine that the list of students contains a huge number of elements, and there are more names than Jonh, Mary and Ben.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be implemented with Stream API in the following way:

1. Create a map of names to the appropriate getters of `Student` class
2. Create another map of names to the getters for `IntSummaryStatistics` class
3. Build a map with `Collectors.groupingBy` + `Collectors.summarizingInt` to get the stats per student, and transform this map with `Collectors.toMap` to get required stats parameter by the student.

**Update**
An enum may be implemented to store references to appropriate getters in `Student` and `IntSummaryStatistics`, then the map should use the enum values.

```java
enum FieldStat {
    AGE_AVERAGE(Student::getAge, IntSummaryStatistics::getAverage),
    HEIGHT_MAX(Student::getHeight, IntSummaryStatistics::getMax),
    WEIGHT_MIN(Student::getWeight, IntSummaryStatistics::getMin);

    private final ToIntFunction<Student> field;
    private final Function<IntSummaryStatistics, Number> stat;

    FieldStat(ToIntFunction<Student> getter, Function<IntSummaryStatistics, Number> stat) {
        this.field = getter;
        this.stat = stat;
    }

    public ToIntFunction<Student> getField() {
        return field;
    }

    public Function<IntSummaryStatistics, Number> getStat() {
        return stat;
    }
}
```

Example implementation:

```java
List<Student> students = Arrays.asList(
    new Student("John", 35, 177, 78), new Student("John", 29, 173, 72),
    new Student("Mary", 32, 164, 58), new Student("Mary", 28, 167, 56),
    new Student("Ben",  24, 181, 84), new Student("Ben",  27, 169, 65),
    new Student("Bob",  35, 178, 80)
);

Map<String, FieldStat> mapStat = Map.of(
        "John", FieldStat.AGE_AVERAGE,
        "Mary", FieldStat.HEIGHT_MAX,
        "Ben",  FieldStat.WEIGHT_MIN
);

Map<String, Number> stats = students.stream()
    .filter(st -> mapStat.containsKey(st.getName()))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Student::getName,
        Collectors.summarizingInt(st -> mapStat.get(st.getName()).getField().applyAsInt(st))
    ))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Map.Entry::getKey, 
        e -> mapStat.get(e.getKey()).getStat().apply(e.getValue())
    ));

System.out.println(stats);
```

Output

```
{John=32.0, Ben=65, Mary=167}
```

Comment: Great answer! But I would like to know why is this solution more efficient than iterating over the list. This is not a "How to do it" question, this is more a "Which way is better and why". Thanks!

Comment: Instead of two separate maps for the getters, you could create an enum containing the name along with the functions.

Comment: The performance is comparable to iterating by list because the input list is iterated only one time.  Main advantage of this solution is that it allows to provide custom calculations in a declarative way by adding entries to the map(s) without changing much code.  Also, a single map may be implemented with values combining the references to the getters in `Student`  and `IntSummaryStatistics`

Comment: @daniu, enum may be fine too if it's not bound to specific name but rather to the field in `Student` and the stats, then a map should be used for dynamic names as keys and enum as values.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're thinking of the right problems. You could certainly try looping to avoid multiple passes over the same stream of data. However, there are also more fun stream-ways to do this.

```
List<String> goodNames = ...put in names you want to see...;
Map<String, List<Student>> postsPerName = students.stream().filter(goodNames::contains).collect(groupingBy(Student::getName));
```

Then you have a map with only names you care about and all elements matching their names.

Is this the "perfect" solution? Maybe, maybe not. But it's all a balance. Good luck!